# Is the review new or the blog new?

Tags: discussion, design

Because I see that new icon up there but I'm not sure which item it represents. It's difficult to tell if it is supposed to go to the "review" link or the "blog" link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the blog. It'll show a new tag for 24 hours after a blog is posted then return back to normal and the chat link will reappear.

Typically when a link in the header denotes a change it'll show a circular counter with the total items awaiting review.

Comment: we now limit topbar changes to *just* sites that have per-site blogs, e.g. http://blogoverflow.com and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the update!